# Why can't I assign one packed string to another?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, incompatibletypeerror, arrays

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity_(Delphi)) states:

> Two distinct types are compatible if they satisfy at least one of the following conditions.
>
> Both are packed-string types with the same number of characters.

However, in Delphi Tokyo this doesn't compile:

```
procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LSource: packed array [0..3] of Char;
  LTarget: packed array [0..3] of Char;
begin
  LSource := '1234';
  LTarget := LSource; // ← ← ← E2008 Incompatible types
  ShowMessage(LTarget);
end;
```

There is not much documentation about packed strings. Using a `packed array[1..4]` breaks the assignment from the string literal. And removing the `packed` identifier makes no change at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: Used the classic Win32 compiler.

Comment: The code doesn't compile in XE2 either, so this is not a new issue.  Your variables are using distinct packed-string types of the same length, so *in theory* they should be type-compatible and assignment-compatible, per the documentation, but *in reality* they are not.

Comment: Declaring the array type and using the same type for all variables would be a simple solution.

Comment: IOW, the code will work fine if you use `var LSource, LTarget: packed array [0..3] of Char;` or `type T4CharArray = packed array [0..3] of Char; var LSource: T4CharArray; LTarget: T4CharArray;` so that `LSource` and `LTarget` are using the same type instead of separate distinct types.